# ラズパイに格納したCSVデータを1秒ごとに1行ずつ抜き出し、MQTTを利用してIoTプラットフォームへ送信(転送)したい

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, csv

表題の通り、1秒ごとの数値が1列ずつに格納されているCSVデータを読み取り、
1秒おきにIoTプラットフォームへ全くそのまま送信したいと考えております。

現在のコードは以下です。

```
### CSV_to_.py

import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

# Set Parameters
ADDR = "********"
PORT = "********"
TOPIC = "********"
QOS = "********"
ID = "********"　#本来のコードには実値が入っています

#CSVファイルをリスト形式で出力
f = '20210902.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding="shift-jis").values.tolist()

for row in df:
    DATA = ',' . join(map(str,row))
　　print(DATA)

    cmd = "mosquitto_pub --host " + str(ADDR) +" --port "+ str(PORT) + " --qos 0 --topic " + str(TOPIC) + " -m '," + str(DATA) + ", ' -i " + str(ID)
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)

    time.sleep(1)
```

上記コードを実行すると、

```
2021/9/2 5:02,0,22.8,1.5,0,0,2.7,98,0,1
Error: The connection was lost.
```

と表記されラズパイ内でのデータ表示は可能ですが
IoTプラットフォームへデータが送信できていない状態です。
どなたか修正方法についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。

IoTプラットフォーム側で受け取る値が、strで全項目文字列として
取り扱われているのではないかと設定を見直したところ正常にデータ送信が可能となりました。
皆さまのご意見大変参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `DATAに値が入っておらず`というのはどのように確認したのでしょうか？ 例えば`cmd = ...`と`proc = ...`の間に`print(cmd)`としたり、`cmd = ...`の先頭の`mosquitto_pub`を何か引数を画面表示するとか何かのファイルに追記するだけのプログラムに挿し替えてみて、どのような文字列になるかを確かめて質問に追記してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: can110さん回答の関連記事。[戻り値をマスターしよう！Pythonのreturn文の使い方を簡単解説](https://www.tech-teacher.jp/blog/python-return/), [【Python入門】関数で使うreturn文とprint関数の違いについての初歩的な説明](https://1978works.com/2021/10/28/how-to-understand-differences-between-return-statement-and-print-function-in-python/), [Python 関数 戻り値とは](https://aiacademy.jp/texts/show/?id=572), [Python 3: print と return について（超基礎）](https://qiita.com/orange_u/items/5a769459dcaa5e06c15b)

Comment: 問題を切り分けてください。
cmdに格納されているコマンド文字列を、通常のシェル上で手入力して実行した場合は正常に動作するでしょうか？

Comment: エラーは「接続が切れた」と出ているので、CSV が1秒おきで一日分だとデータが多過ぎて切れている可能性もあります。小さいデータでも再現するか、辺りを試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: cmdに格納されているコマンドを手入力で実施すると、正常に転送できていることが確認できました。
mosquitto_pub --host <ホスト名> --port 1883 --qos 0 --topic <トピック名> -m ',2021/9/2 5:02,0,22.8,1.5,0,0,2.7,98,0,1' -i <端末名> -d
にてコマンド実行しました。

Comment: 解決に至った情報は質問に追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保つべきです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATAに値（文字列）をセットしたいのであれば、printの実行結果はNoneなので`DATA = print(',' . join(map(str,row)))`ではなく`DATA = ',' . join(map(str,row))`とすべきだと思います。